# How to define a class that sends an action like NSButton?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, action

In Cocoa, how do you define a class that sends an action? I want to be able to connect the action to the selector of another object in IB in the style of NSButton. I would prefer not to subclass NSControl if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give it a property (informal is fine) holding an `id`, for the target. I'm not sure whether this should retain or not; I'd say no, since the target will normally be the controller that owns the window that (indirectly) owns the view.
2. Give it a property (informal in fine) holding a `SEL`, for the action.
3. Respond to `mouseUp:` and `keyDown:` (checking that the key in question is the space bar or return or enter) by sending yourself an `accessibilityPerformAction:` message, passing `NSAccessibilityPressAction`.
4. Respond to [the `accessibilityPerformAction:` message](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSAccessibility_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/accessibilityPerformAction:) by either sending your action message to your target (`NSAccessibilityPressAction`) or calling up to `super` (other), as described in the documentation for that method.

You should also implement the rest of the [NSAccessibility protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSAccessibility_Protocol/) while you're at it. Test that work with a mix of the Accessibility Inspector and VoiceOver.

Comment: Thanks Peter! That's what I was looking for.